# Rails 6, ActiveRecord and Mysql 8, how set the length of a string field to 512 chars?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, mysql-8.0

There are many examples that explains how to create text fields of different lengths but only having these options:

- Tiny: 256 bytes (string equivalent in Rails)
- Text: 65_535 bytes (text equivalent in Rails)
- Medium Text: 16_777_215 bytes
- Long Text: 4_294_967_295 bytes

All the references I have found are very old (>3 years old). Is this still valid?

I want to create a string field of 512 chars. Should I go for a `Text` column? Looks like a waste of space. Can I crate a specific field of 512 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in the new versions the Mysql text fields allow more granualirity in the field size.

If I do this in a migration:

```
change_column :scrapers, :url, :string, limit: 512
```

I see this in the sql log:

```
ALTER TABLE `scrapers` CHANGE `url` `url` varchar(512) NOT NULL
```

And this in the mysql table structure:

```
`url` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
```